# Substitution: capture Confirmation flag answer

Tags: regex, vim, replace, substitution, confirmation

I want to do a substitute in lines only with a certain pattern using the confirmation flag:

```
g/'pattern'/s/'search'/'replace'/gc
```

The c (confirm) flag tells ":substitute" to ask for confirmation before it performs each substitution:

```
Replace with 'replace-pattern' (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?
```

The problem is that it is a global substitution and `q` has no effect.

I would like to capture the input the user gives at above question.
Is it `q` do this
Is it `n`' do this
etc

Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to do that in your script? then search those occurrences by yourself, provide hint msg to user, then you can catch inputs.

Comment: @Kent, Yes in a script. I searches those occurrences now in a function. Check every line and do a substitute with confirmation. How do I provide hint msg to user?

Comment: @Kent, Providing hint message to user? Yes if I know how to do this :) Echo message? Echom? I don't know what you mean with hint msg to user;)

Comment: chk input() if it helps

Comment: Confirmation flag is a system command, still don't understand how to capture this with input(). Input() is a user dialog, no? Btw am I asking too much help?

Comment: what I meant is, you do the confirmation, search, replacement by on your own, in your script.